# /usr/bin/perl -e "statement" doesn't accept variables

Tags: perl, shell

I'd like to execute following perl script as a oneliner:

```
perl -e 'print "my $var = "Hello "; print $var."World\n";'
```

this ends in following error message:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ""$var = "Hello"
(Missing operator before Hello?)
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "Hello "; print $var.""
(Do you need to predeclare Hello?)
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "World\"
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, at end of line
(Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near ""$var = "Hello "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

following statement however works perfectly:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello "; print "World\n";'
```

It seems perl -e doesn't accept variables. Is this true and if yes, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra `"`:

```
perl -e 'print "my $var = "Hello "; print $var."World\n";'   
#      here  __^
```

delete it.

But it is not realy clear what you want.

Comment: I guess you want `perl -e 'my $var = "Hello "; print $var, "World\n"'`; so, an extra `print` as well.

Comment: @tripleee: probably, but who knows?